# OpenID ANd OpenAuth SQL Membership Database Implementation for ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, asp.net-membership, openid

I try to use OpenId in ASP.NET MVC4, SO I use [This Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/12/integrate-openauth-openid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers.aspx), And as you see in **Database Structure** we need some additional tables to support OpenId and OpenAuth, as usual I use

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\aspnet_regsql.exe

to implement Membership Database,

I install Visual Studio 2012 with .NETFramework 4.5 and MVC 4 so I run the `aspnet_regsql.exe` but the created database is not contain additional tables to support OpenId, So is there another way to implement this Database? Or I should add additional database by my own? and if yes how implement needed membership structure in Code side?

I think there must be an auto way (like before) to implement membership to support new OpenId feature, what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, MVC 4 does not use the old membership tables, but rather a new membership system called SimpleMembership that has a very different table structure.  You don't use aspnet_regsql, but rather let SimpleMembership create the tables automatically.

If you generate a default internet application with MVC 4, it creates all the code necessary to enable openid and openauth.  This is built into the default sample. The example you linked to is for the Universal providers.  They too, by the way, have a different table structure than the old SqlMembership system.